Issue with Animating Width Change in Flexbox
I'm trying to animate the width of a navbar in the following code.
The navbar should expand in width when hovered over, but I want only the nav-title__text to grow, while the icon remains the same size. However, the SVG icon slightly shifts to the left during the animation.
What is causing this, and how can I prevent it?


:root {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #23232e;
  width: 4rem;
  transition: width 1s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}

nav:hover {
  width: 10rem;
  color: white;
}

.nav-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.nav-title>svg {
  height: 2rem;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.nav-title__text {
  flex-grow: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

nav:hover .nav-title__text {
  width: fit-content;
}
<nav>
  <div class="nav-title">
    <svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="#ff69b4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5">
      <path d="M1.75 11 8 14.25 14.25 11M1.75 8 8 11.25 14.25 8M8 1.75 1.75 5 8 8.25 14.25 5z" /></svg>
    <div class="nav-title__text">
      Title
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>




It is because as a flex item, the svg's width was shrinked without nav being expanded, and the shrinking amount changes with the nav's width. Setting flex-grow:0 on it doesn't do anything until the nav grows large enough to start growing its flex items instead of shrinking.
You can set flex:0 0 auto on the svg instead, but you will notice it won't be centered anymore:


:root {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #23232e;
  width: 4rem;
  transition: width 1s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

nav:hover {
  width: 10rem;
  color: white;
}

.nav-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.nav-title>svg {
  height: 2rem;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.nav-title__text {
  flex-grow: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

nav:hover .nav-title__text {
  width: fit-content;
}
<nav>
  <div class="nav-title">
    <svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="#ff69b4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5">
        <path d="M1.75 11 8 14.25 14.25 11M1.75 8 8 11.25 14.25 8M8 1.75 1.75 5 8 8.25 14.25 5z" /></svg>
    <div class="nav-title__text">
      Title
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>



If you want it to be centered before nav being expanded, and remain in the same size and position when the nav is growing, you can simply use a custom property to store the original nav's width (4rem in your case):


:root {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav {
  --orig-w: 4rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #23232e;
  width: var(--orig-w);
  transition: width 1s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

nav:hover {
  width: 10rem;
  color: white;
}

.nav-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.nav-title>svg {
  height: 2rem;
  flex: 0 0 var(--orig-w);
}

.nav-title__text {
  flex-grow: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

nav:hover .nav-title__text {
  width: fit-content;
}
<nav>
  <div class="nav-title">
    <svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="#ff69b4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5">
        <path d="M1.75 11 8 14.25 14.25 11M1.75 8 8 11.25 14.25 8M8 1.75 1.75 5 8 8.25 14.25 5z" /></svg>
    <div class="nav-title__text">
      Title
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



